# C# Regex.Split

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a particular problem in complex string:

string mode:

```
     Description,Title,ContentFooterLeft[JE_Boxes: Identifier,Box,Namespace,Title,Channels,PriorityChannels,ForceChannel,SingleQuery,Template,Elements[JE_Example: Lead],LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],],],Keywords
```

Tree mode:

```
Description,
Title,
ContentFooterLeft
    [
        JE_Boxes: 
                Identifier,
                Box,
                Namespace,
                Title,
                Channels,
                PriorityChannels,
                ForceChannel,
                SingleQuery,
                Template,
                Elements
                    [
                        JE_Example:
                                Lead
                    ],
                LastNews
                    [
                        JE_Article: 
                                Lead,
                                Galeria
                                    [
                                        JE_Gallery:
                                                Title,
                                                Banner 
                                                    [
                                                        JE_Banner: 
                                                                Title
                                                    ],
                                    ],
                    ],
    ],
Keywords
```

And my objective with Regex.Split its something like this:

1º [Step] Call function:

```
Regex.Split("Description,Title,ContentFooterLeft[JE_Boxes: Identifier,Box,Namespace,Title,Channels,PriorityChannels,ForceChannel,SingleQuery,Template,Elements[JE_Example: Lead],LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],],],Keywords", "Regex expression")
```

1º Result:

```
Description
Title
ContentFooterLeft[JE_Boxes:Identifier,Box,Namespace,Title,Channels,PriorityChannels,ForceChannel,SingleQuery,Template,Elements[JE_Example: Lead],LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],],]
Keywords
```

2º [Step] Call function:

```
Regex.Split("ContentFooterLeft[JE_Boxes:Identifier,Box,Namespace,Title,Channels,PriorityChannels,ForceChannel,SingleQuery,Template,Elements[JE_Example: Lead],LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],],]", "Regex expression")
```

2º Result:

```
JE_Boxes
Identifier
Box
Namespace
Title
Channels
PriorityChannels
ForceChannel
SingleQuery
Template
Elements[JE_Example: Lead]
LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],]
```

3º [Step] Call function:

```
Regex.Split("Elements[JE_Example: Lead]", "Regex expression")
Regex.Split("LastNews[JE_Article: Lead, Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],],]", "Regex expression")
```

3º Result:

```
JE_Example
Lead
```

AND

```
JE_Article
Lead
Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],]
```

4º [Step] Call function:

```
Regex.Split("Galeria [JE_Gallery: Title,Banner [JE_Banner: Title],]", "Regex expression")
```

4º Result:

```
JE_Gallery
Title
Banner [JE_Banner: Title]
```

5º [Step] Call function:

```
Regex.Split("Banner [JE_Banner: Title]", "Regex expression")
```

5º Result:

```
JE_Banner
Title
```

Obvious when i know the regular(s) expression(s) i will make this in a recursive method...
Sorry for my long text, but this is the best way to present my problem...

Comment: that's a lot of details, but I'm afraid I can't find what the question is. could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case it might actually be easier to write a parser than a regular expression. You could use [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), which is an excellent and easy to use library.

Comment: Thanks, this was my "Did you know?" moment of the day :)